# How can I get text from a dialog?

Tags: c, dialog, gtk, gtkentry

I need to get text from an entry in a dialog, like a login dialog (get the user and password), I've tryied to use 'gtk_entry_get_text' but I did something wrong or there's something else I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the text from an entry widget in a dialog, you should use gtk_entry_get_text.

```
char* entry_content;
entry_content = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_widget));
```

You should take care of this things:

- First, you should pass the entry widget as a parameter, not the window dialog or other widget.
- You should cast the GtkWidget into a GtkEntry.
- The returning string is allocated by the GtkEntry, so you **must not** free it.